# JTable Swing retrieve data

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm trying to populate a table with data from a database however i am having some issues with it. Could someone provide me with an example? (so the table takes in an Object[][] parameter for the data). I have the following basic code to display a table ;

```
class table extends JFrame
{
    JTable table; 

    public table()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        String[] columnNames = {"test","test","test"};
        Object[][] data= {{"test","test","test"},{"test","test","test"}};

        table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,100));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

       JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
       add(scrollPane); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? Please see the documentation: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two years ago, during my time in technical school, I wrote a little library help solve some of the problems proposed by the exercises, which included a a [`DatabaseTableModel`](http://beibinutils.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/beibinutils/beibinutils/file/fa6933cb32ab/src/beibin/utils/swing/table/DatabaseTableModel.java).

The class extends from `AbstractTableModel`, [which means you can set it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel%28javax.swing.table.TableModel%29) as the your `JTable`'s data source.

Here's the algorithm that constructs a model from a `ResultSet`:

```
public final void constructModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    rs.last();
    rowCount = rs.getRow();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    // DatabaseColumn simply holds a name and a Class<?>.
    columns = new DatabaseColumn[columnCount];
    // This is the Object[][] array that you were talking about.
    // It holds all the data from the ResultSet.
    data = new Object[columnCount][rowCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
        // Figure out the column name and type.
        int j = i + 1;
        String colName = rsmd.getColumnLabel(j);
        Class<?> colClass = String.class;
        try {
            colClass = Class.forName(rsmd.getColumnClassName(j));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            colClass = String.class;
        }
        columns[i] = new DatabaseColumn(colName, colClass);
        // Get the data in the current column as an Object.
        rs.beforeFirst();
        for (int k = 0; rs.next(); ++k) {
            data[i][k] = rs.getObject(j);
        }
    }
    // Notify listeners about the changes so they can update themselves.
    fireTableStructureChanged();
}
```

The class worked when I used it in school, but it isn't exactly production code. When I look at it today, I start to see problems.

One problem is that it is loading the *entire contents* of the `ResultSet` into memory. Could get ugly pretty quickly.

Also, the algorithm isn't exactly optimal. It loops around with the database cursor as if it was nothing; I *suppose* that it would be less costly for the database if it had retrieved all the objects in the current row first and assigned them to their appropriate columns *before* moving on to the next row.

Nevertheless, I think it is a good enough starting point.